# OpenLayers zoom selected feature

Tags: openlayers-2, select, zoom

In our OpenLayer.js we first call the maximum extent of the map:

```
"maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds (X1, Y1, X2, Y2),".
```

After the layer definition follows

```
"map.addLayers ([lyr1, layer3, layer4]);" and "map.zoomToMaxExtent ();".
```

In between, the variable for `"OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature"` is defined. Our problem now is that after our feature query, the map always returns to "MaxExtent".

Does anyone have an idea, how after the feature query the zoom level does not change?

In our OpenLayer.js we first call the maximum extent of the map:

```
"maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds (X1, Y1, X2, Y2),"
```

After the layer definition follows `"map.addLayers ([lyr1, layer3, layer4]);"` and `"map.zoomToMaxExtent ();"`. In between, the variable for "OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature" is defined. Our problem now is that after our feature query, the map always returns to "MaxExtent".

Does anyone have an idea, how after the feature query the zoom level does not change?

After selected feature, the zoom should not change. We only want the "MaxExtent" when loading the map for the first time.

Comment: Question is repated twice (with slight variation). It would be easier to read of that was corrected.